# Find the first index such that all successive elements are zero

Tags: matlab

I have a vector in matlab

```
a = [1 8 0 7 0 5 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Here I am interested to FIND the first index (beyond which the value are completely zero) where the zeros occur continuously. In this example I expect the answer to be `8`.

Comment: What if the last element of the vector is nonzero? What should the result be if `a= [2 0 4 0 0 5]`?

Comment: @Dan - I would interpret this as returning empty / null as there are no successive elements that are continuously 0.  I think the OP needs to adjust the wording of the question to state whether or not they want to find a continuous stream of zeroes (i.e. going until the end of the array) or find the longest stream of zeroes.

Comment: @Dan I think for `[2 0 4 0 0 5]`, it has two groups of continuous zeros, one that starts at `2` and another that starts at `4`. So it has to be `4`. I will let OP confirm that though.

Comment: @rayryeng ...or the last group of zeros. This is exactly why I'm asking the OP to clarify.

Comment: Hello there asker! Could you clarify on the confusion regarding the case when the last element is non-zero? Confusing questions don't add much value to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
last_idx = max(find(a~=0)) + 1
```

however, if your last entry is not a zero you've to be careful...

Comment: Although ``find(a~=0)`` might be easier to read, you get the same result with just ``find(a)``.

Answer (score 4):

One approach that works even if your last entry is non-zero or your first entry is zero or all your entries are zero, covers just about everything.

```
find(diff([1 a]==0)==1,1,'last')
```

Note that this finds the location of the last group of zeros.

Comment: Does this have any advantage over the simpler answer of @Dan? (Which was posted later)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Yes, this answer returns the last non-zero number before a zero. My answer just returns the last non-zero number

Comment: @Dan I see, probably that is not intended. For `a=[1 8 0 7 0 5 9]` it returns 5 instead of 8, whilst 'beyond the fifth element all elements are zero' does not hold.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Granted, but the answer still has value as someone looking for this in the future might find their way here as the problem statement is very similar

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin OP is looking to find the first index of the last group of `continuous zeros`. That's why for `[1 8 0 7 0 5 9]`, the last group of zeros would start at `5`. I think Dan has interpreted the problem differently, as his solution finds the `non-zeros` rather.

Comment: @Divakar I don't read that in the question, but if it turns out that this does (or is made to) answer the question just alert me and I will be glad to change my vote.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I think that the question is ambiguous and that this is a completely fair interpretation of what is being asked. I would personally suggest that you change your vote regardless of whether the OP comes back or not

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - I agree with Dan.  The OP was not very clear on the edge cases of the problem.  The definition of downvotes from the FAQ is: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.".  This is not **dangerously** incorrect, certainly shows effort and *not* sloppy.  This is simply another interpretation of the question where we had to fill in some of the blanks. I also recommend you change your vote as this can be interpreted in more than one way. BTW Divakar I +1ed you.

Comment: @rayryeng Appreciate the support guys! :) I think if Dennis reads through the problem and comments around here, it might make more sense to him! This is one thing that bugs me, the quality of questions posted here.

Comment: I downvoted because I couldn't see how this could be what the asker would need. (Not because I could see he might want something else). I still don't see it but as others clearly do I guess there is no need for a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

`find` pretty much does this for you:

```
find(a, 1, 'last') + 1
```

since `find` just returns a list of the positions of non-zero characters, all you have to do is ask `find` to only give you the last such element and then the next element (hence the `+1`)

Comment: I think OP was looking to find the first index of the "last" group of zeros. Does this code works on that?

Comment: Still a smart solution if that final element is not non-zero! Maybe OP wasn't considering such a situation at the first place. +1